# SASS dependency not found in Laravel and Vue.js project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I inherited a Laravel project that uses Vue.js as the front end.  However, I can't seem to get things to work.

Here are the commands I executed:

```
john@mail:~/$ cd ~/html/app
john@mail:~/html/app$ composer install
john@mail:~/html/app$ php artisan migrate ---> at this point the website is viewable, so i guess all the npm resources were already compiled with the project
john@mail:~/html/app$ npm install
john@mail:~/html/app$ npm run watch
```

But the last command yielded the results below.

> @ watch /var/www/html/app cross-env NODE_ENV=development
> node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules
> --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active Webpack is watching the
> files…
> 95% emitting                              ERROR  Failed to compile
> with 14 errors
> 7:16:18 PM
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - /var/www/html/app/resources/assets/sass/app.scss in multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
> /var/www/html/app/resources/assets/sass/app.scss

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.35.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "foundation": "^4.2.1-1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "lang.js": "^1.1.14",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue? To me, the instruction to `npm install --save /var/www/html/app/resources/assets/sass/app.scss` doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

You have eight outdated packages in your package.json. You may want to start there and see what errors if any, come next.

```
 axios             ^0.17  →     ^0.21     
 bootstrap-sass   ^3.3.7  →    ^3.4.1     
 cross-env        ^5.1.3  →    ^7.0.3     
 jquery             ^3.2  →      ^3.6     
 laravel-mix        ^1.0  →      ^6.0     
 lodash          ^4.17.4  →  ^4.17.21     
 sass            ^1.35.1  →   ^1.35.2     
 vue              ^2.5.7  →   ^2.6.14
```

Update your package.json with the following and then run `npm run prod`.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "foundation": "^4.2.1-1",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "lang.js": "^1.1.14",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```